# Question on proving $\lim_{x\to a^{+}} f(x)$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

Here's what I have to prove:
Let $f$ be defined on the interval $(a,b)$ and suppose that $f$ is increasing and bounded on $(a,b)$. Then prove that $\lim_{x\to a^{+}} f(x)$ exists.

To prove $\lim_{x\to a^{+}} f(x)$ exists, I defined $L:=\inf \{ f(x): x\in (a,b)\}$ and claimed that $\lim_{x\to a^{+}} f(x) = L$. Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. Then there exists $x' \in (a,b)$ such that $L\le f(x') < L+\epsilon $. Now, let $\delta = x' -a$. If $a<x<a+\delta = x'$ then $f(x) \le f(x') < L+ \epsilon $ i.e. $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon $.

Is my proof correct? Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Your proof if fine **if** the statement that you want to prove contains the word “decreasing” instead of “increasing”.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I don't see it. I used "increasing" in thar part where I say $x<x'$ then $f(x) \le f(x')$.

Comment: I made a mistake (I was thinking about the limit at $b$). I will delete the other comment and this one too. Your proof is fine.

Comment: You'd just need to add $L \le f(x) \le \cdots$ (or $L - \epsilon < L \le f(x) \le f(x') < L + \epsilon$) near the end to be able to conclude $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.